# how we can simplify the complexity time of T(n) = O(n3 + 2n2 + 3n) + T(n-1)

Tags: time-complexity

how we can simplify the complexity time of **T(n) = O(n^3  + 2n^2  + 3n) + T(n-1)**
the result should be **O(n^4)** but how?
It can be solved using General Theorem?

Comment: `T(n)` = `O(n^3+2n^2+3n)+T(n-1)` = `O(n^3)+T(n-1)` = `O(n^3)+O(n^3)+T(n-2)` = ... = `n*O(n^3)` = `O(n^4)`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.